# Why diff3 on inputs from process substitution finds a difference while diff3 on same data in files finds no difference?

Tags: diff, diff3

diff3 on files finds no difference:

```
$ grep -P '\[\[.*?\]\]' -o intro.tex | sort > A.txt
$ grep -P '\[\[.*?\]\]' -o intro.tex | sort | uniq > B.txt
$ grep '\\pnum %% \[\[' intro.tex | sed 's/\\pnum %% //' | sort > C.txt
$ diff3 A.txt B.txt C.txt | wc -l
0
```

diff3 on process substitutions running the same commands finds a difference:

```
$ diff3 \
  <(grep -P '\[\[.*?\]\]' -o intro.tex | sort) \
  <(grep -P '\[\[.*?\]\]' -o intro.tex | sort | uniq) \
  <(grep '\\pnum %% \[\[' intro.tex | sed 's/\\pnum %% //' | sort) | wc -l
95
```

Why? Any ideas?

A minimum reproducer:

```
$ echo test > a
$ diff3 a a a
$ diff3 <(cat a) <(cat a) <(cat a)
====1
1:1c
  test
2:0a
3:0a
```

Comment: What do your eyes tell you? Is there a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we run `diff3` under `strace -f`:

```
$ strace -qqfe execve -e signal=none diff3 a b c
execve("/usr/bin/diff3", ["diff3", "a", "b", "c"], 0x7ffef2bb2d78 /* 53 vars */) = 0
[pid 13360] execve("/usr/bin/diff", ["diff", "--horizon-lines=100", "--", "b", "c"], 0x7ffc019c6d50 /* 53 vars */) = 0
[pid 13361] execve("/usr/bin/diff", ["diff", "--horizon-lines=100", "--", "a", "c"], 0x7ffc019c6d50 /* 53 vars */) = 0
```

As you can see `diff3` calls `diff` twice, and the third file is one of the operands for both invocations.

With ksh-style `<(...)` process substitution, the file is a pipe.

```
cmd1 <(cmd2)
```

is the same as:

```
cmd2 | cmd1 /dev/fd/0
```

except that a fd other than 0 is used.

So, for the third argument to `diff3`, the first `diff` will consume the whole input, the second will have nothing left to read, so the file will appear empty.

So the third argument at least cannot be a pipe¹.

If using `zsh`, you can use the `=(...)` form of process substitution that uses a temporary file instead of a pipe:

```
diff3 <(cmd1) <(cmd2) =(cmd3)
```

(the first 2 can still be pipes).

In your case:

```
$ diff3 \
  <(grep -Po '\[\[.*?\]\]' intro.tex | sort) \
  <(grep -Po '\[\[.*?\]\]' intro.tex | sort -u) \
  =(sed -n 's/\\pnum %% \[\[/[[/p' intro.txt | sort)
```

(I've also removed the superfluous `grep` and `uniq` and moved the `-o` option before the non-options).

You could even do some factorisation with:

```
(){ diff3 $1 <(uniq<$1) $2; } =(grep -Po '\[\[.*?\]\]' intro.tex) \
                              =(sed -n 's/\\pnum %% \[\[/[[/p' intro.txt | sort)
```

---

<sup>¹ if the third argument is `-` which `diff3` interprets as reading stdin, then it's the second argument that cannot be a pipe as that's the one that it passes to both `diff` invocations in that case. You'll notice that the manual says: *"**At most one** of
these three file names may be `-`, which tells `diff3` to read the
standard input for that file."*</sup>

Comment: Re: "In your case": in my case (bash) `diff3 <(cmd1) <(cmd2) =(cmd3)` leads to `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`. Any ideas / solutions for bash?

Comment: @pmor, yes, as I said, that's for zsh. In bash, you'll have to create the temp files by hand with `mktemp` or equivalent as bash has no builtin support for creating temp files (older versions used temp files for `<<` and `<<<` which you'd have been able to use on Linux/Cygwin, but that has been replaced with pipes in newer versions).